# DropDownList controls with CascadingDropDown extenders

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I will explain in details what I want exactly.

let say that I have 2 DropDownList controls with CascadingDropDown extender.

DropDownList 1 called car type with CascadingDropDown 1

DropDownList 2 called color with CascadingDropDown 2

For example I selected sport car from first DropDownList then CascadingDropDown 2 will list control 2 with colors available for sport car.

then I selected red color for second car   after that I saved these information to the database.

later on I wanted to modify the record that have these value the red sport car so I will retrieve these value from the database the  DropDownList 1 and DropDownList 2 which have CascadingDropDown externders. to what properties I should assign back these value to have to have first control with sport selected programmatically and second with red value selected programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the pains in working with Cascading Drop Down Lists. The dynamic loading makes it a little more difficult to set the proper values, if you need to edit a record (as opposed to add a new one) where the CDDL is used.

If I recall correctly (it has been a while since I last used it) you set the CDDL `SelectedValue` property. and then it will load the correct data upon rendering the page.

The CDDL takes care of this problem by itself in postbacks, but not in page loads.